# Check whether value exists in specific group of rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this dataframe (`df`):

```
structure(list(from = c("(192) 242-2345", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "(832) 345-3168", 
NA, NA), to = c("(900) 301-3451", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "(900) 234-1231", 
NA, NA), action_result = c("Voicemail", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "IP Phone Offline", "No Answer", "No Answer", "Busy", 
"Busy", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "Busy", "IP Phone Offline", "Busy", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"IP Phone Offline", "IP Phone Offline", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"IP Phone Offline", "No Answer", "No Answer", "Busy", "Missed", 
"Hang Up", "Hang Up")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

The first row contains phone numbers that made the call and received the call. Then, the rows coming after the first row are all NA values. So rows 1-37 are considered as one group, then rows 38 to 40 are considered the second group. I'd like to check if each group contains the value `Call Connected` in `action_result` column.

I've tried `group_by` the `from` and `to` values, but the entire dataset I'm working with has duplicate pairs of `from` and `to` values, so that doesn't work. I'd like a `dplyr` solution to check whether the first 37 rows contain `Call Connected` and output a dataframe with columns:

`from`, `to`, `CallConnected` where `CallConnected` is 1 for Yes and 0 for No.

S0, looking at `df`, the resulting dataset would have 2 rows:

```
from          | to           | CallConnected
--------------------------------------------------
(192) 242-2345|(900) 301-3451| 0
(832) 345-3168|(900) 234-1231| 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using the `tidyverse` package, or you can just load the `dplyr` and the `tidyr` package to achieve this.

The idea is to fill in the `NA` with the closest non-NA value in the `from` and `to` column. After that, use `action_result == "CallConnected"` to check if there are items matching `"CallConnected"`, group by `from` and `to`, and `summarize` with `sum` to count the total matching records.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  fill(from) %>%
  fill(to) %>%
  mutate(CallConnected = action_result == "CallConnected") %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarize(CallConnected = sum(CallConnected)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   from           to             CallConnected
#   <chr>          <chr>                  <int>
# 1 (192) 242-2345 (900) 301-3451             0
# 2 (832) 345-3168 (900) 234-1231             0
```

**Update**

If duplicates are a concern, we can use `rleid` from the `data.table` package to create ID after the `fill` function. Below is an example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create an example with duplication
df_dup <- bind_rows(df, df %>% slice(1:5))

df_dup2 <- df_dup %>%
  fill(from) %>%
  fill(to) %>%
  mutate(ID = rleid(from, to)) %>%
  mutate(CallConnected = action_result == "CallConnected") %>%
  group_by(ID, from, to) %>%
  summarize(CallConnected = sum(CallConnected)) %>%
  ungroup()
df_dup2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID from           to             CallConnected
#   <int> <chr>          <chr>                  <int>
# 1     1 (192) 242-2345 (900) 301-3451             0
# 2     2 (832) 345-3168 (900) 234-1231             0
# 3     3 (192) 242-2345 (900) 301-3451             0
```

Comment: Won't this fail on the real file since there are duplicated `from/to` pairs?

Comment: @thelatemail It seems like there are no duplicates. If that is a concern, we can create a run length ID after the `fill` function to distinguish them.

Comment: Seems like the rleid approach would make sense. OP did note that they had duplicates explicitly in the question "*the entire dataset I'm working with has duplicate pairs of from and to*"

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. I have created an example and added the `rleid` option.